# encountered an error (Early unexpected exit, operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted

Tags: xcode, macos, jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline

```
Testing failed:
    CoreAppTests:
        CoreApp.app (10848) encountered an error (Early unexpected exit, operation never finished bootstrapping - 
        no restart will be attempted. (Underlying error: Crash: CoreApp (10848): Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0x8badf00d))
```

After updating my Mac mini OS to latest and XCode to 11.1 getting the error message. I'm running test cases for an IOS app using Jenkins and Sonar Qube, build is happening perfectly but test cases are not getting executed. Even sometimes i'm getting the following error, and after that the job fails.

> Finished requesting crash reports. Continuing with testing - Jenkins

I even downgraded my XCode back to 10.3 but the issue is still there.

Comment: did you found any solution?

Comment: I'm encountering the same issue like you. Did you find any workaround regarding that. If so, pls share your solution.